# Pass the context to the showdialog so that it is not lost when the start page loads

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, android-context

I am trying to display an information dialog when starting an application.

After closing, another window appears asking for permission. I call it all in the initState function. It works, but I noticed that this first info dialog also closes on its own when 15 seconds have elapsed. As I understand, this is because the application has loaded and the context is lost.

And when I change `runApp(MyApp())` to `runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()))`. It works, the popup doesn't dissapear. But the other showdialogs on other pages didn't close automatically `(Navigator.of(context).pop()`  and `Navigator.pop(context)` doesnt work.

How do I properly pass context to my initial showdialog so that it doesn't disappear when the start page loads?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  static final navKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  const MyApp({Key navKey}) : super(key: navKey);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      final context = MyApp.navKey.currentState.overlay.context;
       await showDialogIfFirstLoaded(context);
       await initPlatformState();
    });
  }
showDialogIfFirstLoaded(BuildContext context, prefs) async {
    bool isFirstLoaded = prefs.getBool(keyIsFirstLoaded);
    if (isFirstLoaded == null) {
      return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          // return object of type Dialog
           return new AlertDialog(
                 // title: new Text("title"),
                 content: new Text("//"),
                 actions: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text(".."),
                    onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(    
      navigatorKey:MyApp.navKey,
      home: new SplashScreen(),}
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => new _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Timer _timer;
  bool _visible = true;
  startTime() async {  
      _timer = Timer(new Duration(seconds: 5), navigationPage); 
  }
  void navigationPage() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 4),
          () => setState(
            () {
          _visible = !_visible;
        },
      ),
    );
    startTime();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Image.asset('images/bg.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: 1200,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 1200,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(''),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: *"After closing, another window appears asking for permission. I call it all in the initState function. It works, but I noticed that this first info dialog also closes on its own when 15 seconds have elapsed."* - you say "After closing", so how the first info dialog can close if it is already closed?

Comment: @pskink i mean, that if I don't click on button Next to close the showdialog, it closes on its own after 15 seconds as it appeared

Comment: @pskink when I open my application, a popup appears with information, when I click on it on the button Next, another popup appears with a request for permission. This is normal application behavior. This is how it works now. But there is a bug that when I load the application and the first popup appears and I will not press anything, but just wait, it will disappear by itself after about 15 seconds and another popup and the loaded first page will appear

Comment: so post the minimal code that shows your case: without any `SharedPreferences`, `FirebaseAnalyticsObserver` etc dependencies, just two `Material` dialogs

Comment: it does not compile, i am unable to run it

Comment: @pskink add home page